# Reporting services URL HTTP 500 error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have issue connecting to the URL `http://<server name>/reports`. I am getting HTTP 500 Internal server error. But the following URL works.
`http://<server name>/reportServer`. Could you please let me know what could be the issue? Thank you.

Comment: Are there any errors on the Application Event Log on the server? Also, you could try and turn on [SSRS tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156500(v=sql.100).aspx) to see if that yields anything...but I would look in the Application Event Log first

Comment: Here is the error I see when I run the report. 'An error occurred in the HTTP Runtime object for application domain ReportServer'.

Comment: Hi, is that the error you get through your browser? If so, do you have access to log onto the server where Reporting Services is hosted? You should log in there to check the Application Event Log or enable SSRS tracing....The info (& error) is very generic so it's hard to provide a concrete solution, at this stage I can only really try and point to where more useful error information would live

Comment: Yes, the error is from browser. Also I logged in to the server but don't see any errors. I am checking the Trace Log. Where do I see error information?

Comment: If the trace log has nothing then you might want to bump the DefaultTraceSwitch to 4, save your config, access the report via your browser, go back to the trace log and see what if anything gets logged....the [App Event Log](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997769(v=exchg.65).aspx) may also have info (sorry, the link is for MS Exchange Server but the content is still applicable). Also, I am not sure if [this](http://andysal.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/sql-reporting-services-srs-rp-http-500-error-when-browsing-reports-site/) is similar to your situation

Comment: Thank you. The problem was with FIPS policy. We turned it off and it works now. Please post this is an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving from comments to an answer - the issue was the FIPS policy as described [here](http://andysal.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/sql-reporting-services-srs-rp-http-500-error-when-browsing-reports-site/)

Also, for general cases, including a link to [SSRS tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156500%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Your first link is no longer valid.